# Android - conditional disable lint check when a specific annotation is present over a field

Tags: android, lint, butterknife, android-lint

Since I cannot have the ButterKnife binded views to be private (ButterKnife itself denies it), I would like to avoid the lint check of `"Declaration of access can be weaker"` only when I have the ButterKnife annotation "`BindView`" over a field. In all the others cases I want to keep having the Lint to notify me about accesses that can be weaker.

I this case I want to automatically avoid the Lint warning

```
 @BindView(R.id.dl_trader)
    NDrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
```

PS = I would like to avoid to manual insert the `@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")` every time I bind a view with ButterKnife. Is there any other automatic way?

Comment: Android Studio should not complain about that, because view fields will be used from generated code (from the same package, so package private access is OK).